# git re-add only those files that have already been staged

Tags: git

I often have a situation where I have `git add`ed a set of files for a commit, but then have to make a modification to those files so end up with the modifications on those same files in `Changed but not updated`.

Is there a one liner I can execute to `git add` only the files that exist in `Changed but not updated` and `Changes to be committed` lists?

```
markdsievers$git status
# On branch master
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   src/com/foo/Bar.java
#   modified:   src/com/foo/Foo.java
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   src/com/foo/Bar.java
#   modified:   src/com/foo/Foo.java
#   modified:   src/com/foobar/FooBar.java
```

For the above example I only want `Foo.java` and `Bar.java` but not `FooBar.java` added to the `Changes to be committed:` list.

Comment: Are you thinking of something other than `git add -u`?

Comment: `git add -u` seems to want a filepattern otherwise it uses `.` which would add `Foobar.java`. Yes I could add a filepattern to get my contrived example and that would work, but changes are rarely that simple that a single file pattern would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way:

```
 git add -u $(git status --porcelain | grep ^MM | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Didn't know about `--porcelain`. I didn't think this was an unreasonable feature to ask from git, though perhaps its my workflow that needs adjusting.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me... It tries to add files that are modified but not yet staged.

Comment: +1! But it only works in git root directory, and using `git status -s` instead, it will works in any directory.

Comment: After 6 years since I asked this question I can confidently say this was a workflow problem. Stop making changes on master and `checkout` some feature branches, kid!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer won't work if filenames contain a space. Also -u is useless is this case, but will add all unstaged files if there are no files that are both in `Changed but not updated` and `Changes to be committed` list. Use this instead:

```
git add $(git status -z | perl -0ne 'print $1 if $_ =~ /^MM(.*)$/')
```

This will only work for files that are changed only. If you want this to work for files that are deleted, added, renamed or copied as well, use this:

```
git add $(git status -z | perl -0ne 'print $1 if $_ =~ /^[MADRC][MD](.*)$/')
```

But be careful with last one. For example, if the file is added in index, but its deletion is unstaged, running this command will delete the file in index as well, causing you to lose contents of that file.

**Note that both will work only from root directory of your git repo.**